# I have an Array I need to push into new Array with object mapping

Tags: javascript

This is my Array:

```
[
    {
        "batchno": "B-PI1-1",
        "unitId": 341,
        "productName": "Bar Soap",
        "productProfileId": 3950,
        "qty": 148,
        "returnQty": "20",
        "rate": 10,
        "salesRate": 20,
        "unitName": "PC",
        "gross": 200,
        "net": 200,
        "remarks": "sxzxz"
    },
    {
        "batchno": "B-PI4-1",
        "unitId": 341,
        "productName": "Biscuit",
        "productProfileId": 3951,
        "qty": 700,
        "returnQty": "20",
        "rate": 10,
        "salesRate": 60,
        "unitName": "PC",
        "gross": 200,
        "net": 200,
        "remarks": "zxzxzx"
    }
];
```

I need to push into a new array, but the last one is doubly pushed:

```
if (this.primengTableHelper.initialRecords.length > 0) {
    this.primengTableHelper.initialRecords.map((item: any) => {
        console.log('item', item);
        this.singleItem.batchNo = item.batchno;
        this.singleItem.unitId = item.unitId;
        this.singleItem.productName = item.productName;
        this.singleItem.productProfileId = item.productProfileId;
        this.singleItem.qty = item.qty;
        this.singleItem.returnQty = item.returnQty
        this.singleItem.rate = item.rate;
        this.singleItem.salesRate = item.salesRate;
        this.singleItem.unitName = item.unitName;
        this.singleItem.gross = item.net;
        this.singleItem.net = item.net;
        this.singleItem.remarks = item.remarks;
        this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.paymentNO = this.voucherNO;
        this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.invoiceDate = 
            this.maxInvoiceDateFilter.toString();
        this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.damageStockDetailsListDto
            .push(this.singleItem);
    });
```

Comment: Please format your question code properly so we can read it, and maybe use a [mcve] so it can be debugged.

Comment: the singleItem is an object model here

Comment: @Andy do u have any idea

Comment: It doesn't look like you should be using `map` at all. `map` returns a new array. You probably want `forEach` or a [simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). By "doubly pushed" do you mean it's pushed in twice, or that it's nested?

Comment: suppose the last record added to new array is twise my aim is i want all record to push new array but the last one is pushed two times

Comment: Why is `net` assigned to `gross`? Is there some logic behind that, or a mistake?

Comment: I used for loop the result is same

Comment: @trincot that not consider

Comment: What does that mean: *"that not consider"*? Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep pushing `this.singleItem`, which is *one* object, no matter how many iterations are made. In each iteration that single object is *mutated*, and then pushed again, resulting in multiple references to the same object.

Instead, make sure to create a *new* object in each iteration. At the same time avoid all those individual assignments, and use spread syntax instead:

```
        const newItem = {...this.singleItem, ...item};
        // Make other changes to `newItem` properties if needed...
        // ...
        // Push the new object:
        this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.damageStockDetailsListDto
            .push(newItem);
```

Not your question, but the following lines make no sense in the loop, since they don't depend on the iterated `item`:

```
    this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.paymentNO = this.voucherNO;
    this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.invoiceDate = 
        this.maxInvoiceDateFilter.toString();
```

These statements would always make the same assignment in each iteration. So place them outside that loop.

Note that you shouldn't use `.map` when you don't use the result. Then just use `.forEach`. On the other hand, you can use `.map` to *create* an array for assigning to `this.createOrEditDamageStockDto.damageStockDetailsListDto`. Whether that is a good idea in your case, depends on whether that array already exists before the loop, and has content that should stay there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question. You have an array with two objects. Do you simply want a new array with three objects where the last object is identical to the second one? If so, you could use the ES6 spread operator and do this:

```
const initialRecords = [
  {
    "batchno": "B-PI1-1",
    "unitId": 341,
    "productName": "Bar Soap",
    "productProfileId": 3950,
    "qty": 148,
    "returnQty": "20",
    "rate": 10,
    "salesRate": 20,
    "unitName": "PC",
    "gross": 200,
    "net": 200,
    "remarks": "sxzxz"
  },
  {
    "batchno": "B-PI4-1",
    "unitId": 341,
    "productName": "Biscuit",
    "productProfileId": 3951,
    "qty": 700,
    "returnQty": "20",
    "rate": 10,
    "salesRate": 60,
    "unitName": "PC",
    "gross": 200,
    "net": 200,
    "remarks": "zxzxzx"
  }
]

const recordsWithDuplicate = [
  ...initialRecords,
  initialRecords[initialRecords.length - 1]
]
```

You can read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals

Comment: the issue is when iam try to push this two object to new array with assigining new object model  the last object pushed twise that is the issue in my case

Comment: @Alexbaby okay, so it's a new array and you are not just pushing the objects from the existing array, you are changing their shape, correct? ...and you want two copies of the transformed second object?